# Power tower(infinite tetration)

Tags: tetration

How to find the domain and range of 
$Y=x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}}=x^Y$

I know how to differentiate the function.
I don't know how to proceed further.

We should prove that domain:$[1/(e^e),e^{(1/e)}]$ and range:$[1/e,e]$

Answer (score 0):

As you said:
$$y=x^y$$
and so:
$$\ln(y)=y\ln(x)$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\tag{1}$$
now if we take:
$$L_1=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\ln(y)}{y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}=0$$
If you mean for a given domain that is the range, we can work backwards from $(1)$ to get the domain from the range. Differentiating we get:
$$\frac1x=\left(\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{\ln(y)}{y^2}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x(1-\ln y)}$$
so our minimum/maximum will occur when $y=0$, but to work out $x$ you must evaluate:
$$x=\exp\left(\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\right)$$